# How do I iterate through two lists simultaneously in Haskell?

Tags: sorting, haskell, data-structures, functional-programming, filtering

Essentially what I want to do is this: Given a list comprised of tuples `[(x,[y])]` and another list of strings `[a]`, I want to create a new list of all the `[y]`'s where `x == a` if that makes sense, so if I have `[('a', ['z', 'k', 'x']), ('b', ['z']), ('c', ['y', 'j'])]` and `['a', 'c']`, the resulting list when both lists are passed through the function would be `[['z', 'k', 'x'], ['y', 'j']]`.

The solution I came up with is kind of ridiculous and over complicated, (as well as non-functional) but just so you can see what kind of path I've been thinking about I'll post it below.

```
foo ys xs acc = map (\x -> (map (\(a,y) -> if x == a then y:acc else []) ys)) xs
```

This prints what I want but also prints tons of extra brackets that makes the output super confusing, no doubt because I've bastardized the map function. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given

```hs
l1 = [('a', ['z', 'k', 'x']), ('b', ['z']), ('c', ['y', 'j'])]
l2 = ['a', 'c']
```

a quick and intuitive solution is

```
filter (\(c,_) -> c `elem` l2) l1
```

which filters `l1` retaining only those pairs whose first element is an `elem`ent of `l2`.

The filtering predicate `` (\(c,_) -> c `elem` l2) `` can also be written as `` ((`elem` l2) . fst) ``.

---

As regards performance, if the fact that `l2` is sorted and `l1` is sorted with respect to the `fst`s is just a matter of concidence or oversimplification of the example, we can observe that `filter`ing is a linear operation, because you have to traverse all the elements of `l1` to decide if each one has to be retained or filtered out. But maybe the look up operated by  `` `elem` l2 `` can be improved by making `l2` a `Set`, which is done by simply changing  `` `elem` l2 `` to  `` `elem` Data.Set.fromList l2 ``.

If, instead, the lists are truly sorted as in the example, then other approaches are possible. Just as an example, if `l1` was the same as above, but `l2` was `['d', {-whatever-}]`, then you'd know that the output is empty.

Comment: Thank you, in hindsight that's rather obvious but I appreciate your help all the same.

Comment: `filter (\(c,_) -> c \`elem\` Data.Set.fromList l2) l1` Would this really transform `l2` to a Set once, then efficiently call `elem` on that Set several times? I'm not familiar enough with Haskell, but this looks like it would rebuild the whole Set for every element of `l1`.

Comment: I'm not expert of Haskell, but I deem extremely unlikely that the `Set`  is built everytime. `l2` is immutable, so the result of `Data.Set.fromList l2` can't change while filtering `l1`, so there's no reason why the compiler shouldn't be able to understand that and store the set into the state of the lambda.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the two lists are sorted, like in your example, then you can iterate through both lists simultaneously, using pattern-matching and guards:

```hs
foo ((x,y):xs) (z:zs) | x == z =
foo ((x,_):xs) (z:zs) | x < z =
foo ((x,y):xs) (z:zs) | x > z =
foo [] _ =
foo _ [] =
```

I have intentionally blanked everything after the `=` sign, because I believe you'll learn more if you fill it yourself than if I dump a solution. Although I did leave a small hint by including `y` where it's needed, and `_` instead where it's not needed.

Testing:

```hs
ghci> foo [('a', ['z', 'k', 'x']), ('b', ['z']), ('c', ['y', 'j'])] ['a', 'c']
["zkx","yj"]
```